# Visual Studio Code - Arduino Programming Identifier A8 - A15 (PIN_A8 to PIN_A15) is Undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, undefined

I am attempting to use VSCode to write my Arduino programs (MEGA2560), My issue arises when I try to setup

```
    const int CurrentPin = A9;
```

the A9 is underlined and problems say

```
    identifier "A9" is undefined [7,24]
```

I have tried changing the .vscode/arduino.json .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json

I believe it might be part of the defines in c_cpp_properties

edit: on occasion where I have something being defined by the pin it kicks the can down to the use of it i.e.

line 22

```
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS A13
```

line 24

```
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
```

```
identifier "A13" is undefined [24,17]
```

also when I use the "Go to Definition on the instance of A13 on line 22 it leads back to pins_arduino.h where they are all defined

arduino.json

```
{
    "board": "arduino:avr:mega",
    "configuration": "cpu=atmega2560",
    "port": "/dev/ttyAMC0",
    "output": "build",
    "sketch": "Project/MyProject.ino",
    "programmer": "AVRISP mkII"
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "enableConfigurationSquiggles": true,
    "env", {},
    "configurations": [
        {    
             "name": "Linux",
             "includePath": [
                 "{$workspaceFolder}",
                 %Arduino and library folders%
             ],
             "browse": {
                 "limitSymbolsToIncludeHeaders": false,
                 "path": [
                     "{$workspaceFolder}",
                     %Arduino and library folders%
                 ]
             },
             "defines": [
                 "_DEBUG",
                 "UNICODE",
                 "_UNICODE",
                 "USBCON",
                 "ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR",
                 "ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560",
                 "ARDUINO=10800"
             ],
             "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/avr-gcc",
             "cStandard": "c11",
             "cppStandard": "c++17",
             "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
             "forcedInclude": [
                 "...Arduino.h"
             ]
         }
    ],
    "version": 4

}
```

MyProject.ino

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Libraries.h>

const int currentPin =A9;


void setup(){
//stuff
}
void loop(){
//do stuff
}
```

I expected to uses the defines for the  "ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR" and the "ARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560", to define the analog pins but they do not

Comment: I added the path to pin_arduino.h into the includePath and the browse.path and they appear to be defined. I am not marking as answer because I can not tell if its correct

Comment: Hovering over each instance I get
static const uint8_t A8 = (uint8_t)'>'   ascii(62)

static const uint8_t A9 = (uint8_t)'?'   ascii(63)

static const uint8_t A10 = (uint8_t)'@' ascii(64)

static const uint8_t A11 = (uint8_t)'A'  ascii(65)
static const uint8_t A12 = (uint8_t)'B'  ascii(66)
static const uint8_t A13 = (uint8_t)'C'  ascii(67)
static const uint8_t A14 = (uint8_t)'D'  ascii(68)
static const uint8_t A15 = (uint8_t)'E'   ascii(69)

Any clarification on this

in pins_arduino.h the pins are defined by #define PIN_A(N) (54+N) ie #define PIN_A8 (62)